# finding variable

Tags: c

Purpose: writing a script that takes two parameters (directory and c var) and searches all files with C extension in a directory.

Every line that contains the variable in the second parameter must be printed. The variable should also be matched exactly including capitalization and should be a whole word.

The filename should be printed preceded by the line with the variable

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Comment: "Those who forget grep are doomed to reimplement it badly." ­–Someone, somewhere

Comment: Use `find` to search for all `.c` and `.h` files in a hierarchy, and use `grep` to print the matching lines in those files. Those are common commands to anyone familiar with shell scripting, how can you have "no idea" how to do it? This sounds like homework for a shell script class, don't they teach things first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally never used `ack` so can't comment, but `grep` is great for this

I used this command to look for all files containing the whole word "name" with extensions cpp and h in the directory "unisa".

```
grep -wnr "name" --include *.cpp --include *.h unisa
```

from the man pages

```
-w  Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.
-n  Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file. (you may not want this, but I always use it)
-r Read all files under each directory, recursively
--include Search only files whose base name matches GLOB
```

I ran the command in the example on a directory I have for all my university projects and this is a sample of the output

```
cos2614/assignment_1/question_1/question_1.cpp:15: "Enter your details in the format \"first name: surname: employee number\"");
cos2614/assignment_1/question_2/customer.cpp:3:Customer::Customer(QString name, QString id)
cos2614/assignment_1/question_2/customer.cpp:4:    : m_Name(name), m_ID(id), m_DeliveryAddress(), m_BillingAddress()
cos2614/assignment_1/question_2/test.cpp:12:    QString name, id, address;
cos2614/assignment_1/question_2/test.cpp:14:    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
cos2614/assignment_1/question_2/test.cpp:16:    name = cin.readLine();
cos2614/assignment_1/question_2/test.cpp:22:    Customer cust(name, id);
cos2614/assignment_1/question_2/customer.h:15:        Customer(QString name, QString id);
cos2614/assignment_1/question_5/static3.h:10:        Client(string name): m_Name(name), m_ID(s_SavedID++) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

While `grep` is a general tool, there is a tool, [called `ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/), that is specifically designed for searching source code.  By default, it recursively searches directory trees.  It already has built-in knowledge of which source file extensions are associated with which languages.  For example, to search a directory tree for `c` files in which the name `someName` appears, use:

```
ack --cc '\bsomeName\b' /path/to/
```

Notes:

- `--cc` tells it to search `c`-language files as identified by the extensions `.c`, `.h.` and `.xs`.
- `\bsomeName\b` is the regex to search for.  `\b` means word boundary.  Use it if you want to prevent `anothersomeName` from matching.  `ack` fully supports `perl` regular expressions.
- Searches are recursive by default.  Use `-n` if you don't want to descend into subdirectories.
- If you don't like any of ack's defaults, it is extremely configurable.

On debian-like systems, `ack` was awkwardly renamed `ack-grep` to avoid conflict with a Kanji converter called `ack`.  To install, run `apt-get install ack-grep`.  For other systems, see [How to install ack](http://beyondgrep.com/install/).

Comment: How would something like this be done using grep only?

Comment: `grep -Pr --include='*.[ch]' '\bsomeName\b' /path/to/`

Answer (score 0):

Here, you seem to want to use `grep` to search through all of your files in a directory.

Reading `man grep` will get you a long way with this, but it's particularly worth paying attention to its `--include=GLOB` and `-r` or `--recursive` options.

You can use the recursive flag to avoid the need for `find`, and then the `--include=` flag to specify only files ending with a certain extension.